# "canonical" framing of 3-manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, 3-manifolds, quantum-field-theory

In [Witten's 1989 QFT and Jones polynomial paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-121/issue-3/Quantum-field-theory-and-the-Jones-polynomial/cmp/1104178138.full), he said

> Although the tangent bundle of a three manifold can be trivialized, there is no canonical way to do this.

So if I understand correctly, Witten meant:

> **3-manifold has no canonical framing.**

But in [Atiyah's paper "On framings for 3-manifolds"](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271595/1-s2.0-S0040938300X00961/1-s2.0-004093839090021B/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEDUaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCICjHNQnp9CaLTz7tOSnTHvU257xn3AC%2FOgafw%2Bh5%2B3WGAiBQj3%2FDj4ClWPLT3KEqQq0eey0KO%2B1rl%2B9PiV0oYskQPCq8BQid%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAUaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIM1CDmLafurT%2Fy7eQ2KpAFhVAG4gFFcooS03nZYW4BQXo4PbgYzfYD6x8tGR3oFyYxpkcS0uIlenoZfnWHkBSOz0bCKZBd%2BEkOEbpGjCKok7SZ887EsSZUft1dYF%2FJZ6PDyCFi6%2BRUmfPowemHiH%2BAX22uEHOPdS3PZKqQAAc7WtDkSRjrrCdpxIs7LaYAiL7lKRKxdsWv21aFK97FCt%2BltJJG2xE9Mk3zO79W7cAV9Pz9mRKIbzBaGT9kCKAG0pFFgoryGUodNK9%2FqG4jWMMH5ygciekPJaM9qp2IgstEgf5SdY3KWpaHnR9NflaBzxjILNQRYBnsIYUt8tiHFYrvNAhNCt8LBzSVnAo7yHKZh6TIPVcCZ%2BI5uTqAmTa6Opcym39rR3Nkmmf6ZsfzrH6Uimyu%2FnijEO5V5jbvq7tQ0Nh8Bfla1BZZtfbK1AFilpkzcRJm4fswcF6pFiCzND1KBT%2Fd7Vvdv70YkpvNPQss984XYqHgB5uejBtTzTMYRhawPB2S%2BG%2F%2BBf%2FzCUd3bMYH1YkDPorHMxy2iHx1g7svO55oozoEpb%2F08LYhOyD7x%2BDIbX%2B%2B7HUdrFRIDOWaKKtWnWtE1EkG9E0GxGOUFTwrx2cfUYmIuUiNQBg8eoZdgo0GImvvbg%2FWqSvut3rALkkQhrd%2F8tgjxNGfnMoMUrFwNacRaiWav%2Fd%2BxO7hNhSDiItnym4mkKQXi0T2yep3cxovq9YgTvSKjJa0SDeoKuonQc62orDcVd1YJp9%2FRrfsUag6nnVIgnuH%2FAbWeR0FCTrf3%2BY80PvqPMDAFSGQCqx1V3Iru3vAWFreJJ8soEd5E%2Flizod7PYzCLSiCx4xGECNnqsceNQT1A9M%2BwgXqzQMz0gMMFr220Gllj%2FwT1IupVngwn43FqwY6sgFL9b71XijGJqUyV148dOXQkmTYYoYU%2Biy9r%2BBG5V1oFTih%2FEu5CEdgNiXznXZKKD3brmnjKoHKXR2KNMP2oL4YPX%2B9mQIT%2BKdoGtLMhrNHHZ0q7xXr2YvdvvIBtYmraLGVFwgSYgSyFPZ8Qa6ImVWY%2BM6TiFTdD2AbMlHTvlVfnQp%2BFidxCzTZuyKtcRa2ouooC2VIhgmhxON4icQQvAYxJTwKpNhqkwByHWcnccPrl7N8&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20231207T051419Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY4WX4AQPQ%2F20231207%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=c6957e8aaef073f066fd7a0a60c3a17d41a932ecdf5f0222f065d2162a91375a&hash=0472f383c9fed6e514edd0b218669de3c04e53c6e0bdfad19992a166e35f3b2e&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=004093839090021B&tid=spdf-03238003-5b0a-47b1-be74-3d0db3392423&sid=095519ff39c0e343c46b9d20804e9c6d01f4gxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=0f155d555504565a005552&rr=831a48d06d284ce9&cc=us)
, Atiyah said in his Proposition 1):

> **every oriented 3-manifold has a canonical 2-framing.**

I am puzzled by why 3-manifold has no canonical framing but 3-manifold has a canonical 2-framing. Could someone explain the reason and intuition as simple as possible?

Comment: Presumably the short answer is Witten did not know of a canonical framing at the time, and then Atiyah showed him one.

Comment: And of course, the two mean different things by "framing".

Answer (score 3):

This is maybe not the answer you're looking for, but it's certainly too long for a comment.

First, there's no contradiction here, and nothing too strange. A 2-framing on $M$ is a framing of $TM\oplus TM$, which a priori doesn't have much to do with $TM$ (and moreover it comes with a splitting, which $TM$ doesn't).

Anyway, let me give an answer by analogy. Consider the case of $M = S^1$. Then $TM$ is trivial, but not canonically so: in this case a framing is the same thing as an orientation, or as a nowhere-vanishing section.
$TM\oplus TM$ is also trivial, and either trivialisation of $TM$ induces a "diagonal" trivialisation of $TM \oplus TM$. (Note that Atiyah talks about the diagonal embedding $\Delta\colon SO(3) \to SO(3) \times SO(3)$, which then embeds in $SO(6)$ via an embedding $\iota$.) Moreover, the two induced trivialisations differ by multiplication by $-1$, which on a rank-2 bundle is isotopic to the identity. So the two trivialisations induced are equivalent (as trivialisations of a rank-2 bundle).

**EDIT** <strike>(What follows is slightly speculative.) This should boil down to showing that for every compact oriented 3-manifold $M$ and every map $\tau \colon M \to SO(3)$ (which measures a difference in trivialisations) the composition of maps $\iota\circ\Delta\circ\tau$ is homotopic to a constant map. This is non-trivial even in the case of $M = S^3$, since $\pi_3(SO(6)) = \mathbb{Z}$.</strike>
What mme (is saying that Atiyah) is saying is that, for a 3-manifold $M$, the composition $\iota\circ\Delta\circ\tau$ gives an identification of the induced framings of $TM\oplus TM$ with $\mathbb{Z}$, and in particular there is a preferred framing (the one that corresponds to $0 \in \mathbb{Z}$). See mme's comments below for more details. (Thanks, mme!)

Comment: I don't think the last claim is true. Take $\tau$ to be the identity to see you're asking if the diagonal embedding $SO(3) \to SO(6)$ is null. There are many ways to see that this is false, but here's one: the standard embedding induces an isomorphism on $\pi_3$, and the embedding as the bottom-right block is homotopic to that. Your map is the product of those, so it suffices to show that multiplication induced the sum map on $\pi_3$, which is the Eckmann-Hilton argument. Thus the induced map on $\pi_3$ is injective (it's multiplication by 2, if you like).

Comment: Looking at Atiyah's paper, he's not claiming that there's *one* framing up to homotopy (which appears to be the goal of your last paragraph), he's claiming the framings carry a canonical bijection to the integers, this bijection arising from the Hirzebruch signature formula.

Comment: Oh, nice, thanks Mike! I trusted the OP had the question right... So there's no canonical 2-framing, either, just a canonical bijection with $\mathbb{Z}$, which maybe isn't too far from what is in my answer? (I will edit, or maybe even delete the answer, when I'm sure I got what is needed.)

Comment: Please don't delete the answer! It provides great clarity on the difference between framing $TM$ vs $TM \oplus TM$.

Comment: @MarcoGolla Well, $0 \in \Bbb Z$ is a pretty canonical element, so I'm satisfied with Atiyah calling this a "canonical framing". (More precisely, the bijection is determined by sending a 2-framing $\alpha$ to the integer $\sigma(Z) - p_1(Z, \alpha)$, where $Z$ is an oriented 4-fold bounding $Y$; the `canonical framing' for which this is zero is the one for which Hirzebruch's signature formula is still true.)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is a paper aptly titled [**Canonical framings for 3-manifolds**](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9903056) by Rob Kirby and Paul Melvin.

Here is a 2012 email correspondence between me and Kirby concerning that paper (glad I didn't walk over to his office otherwise I may have forgotten verbally):

- Chris: For a spin 3-manifold M, the spin structure s+s on TM+TM is independent of the choice of spin structure s on TM. Could you explain why?
- Kirby: Here is a down to earth way to think about it. A spin structure is a trivialization over the 1-skeleton which extends (you don't care how) over the 2-skeleton. There are two ways to trivialize over a circle, corresponding to \pi_1 of S(n) n>2, and in the case of n=2 or 1 we work mod 2. Then on s+s, if you change the trivialization of s over a circle, then you double that change for s+s, which mod 0 is no change.